# Which version of node should I install if I want Angular CLI to be supported

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm new to development and I was trying out angular and after I ran "npm install -g @angular/cli" everything got installed properly but when I ran "ng version", I get this error. Can anyone please guide me with this

[image: cmd output]

I tried looking up compatible versions on the Angular docs and API website but there's nothing about node version 20.9.0 not being supported

Comment: Hi, you can find a table of supported versions here: https://angular.io/guide/versions

Comment: Hey James. I did confirm with this table that my current versions were supported but I'm still getting that error message that you can see in the linked image

Comment: Where are you seeing that Node v20 is supported? Angular 16.2.x requires Node ^16.14.0 or ^18.10.0

Comment: I get it now. I thought ^16 meant node v 16 or higher. I'm sorry about the confusion. Thanks James

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of Node is too new (20) for Angular version 16.  According to the compatibility matrix, Angular 16 needs node 16 or 18, not anything newer.

[Compatibility List](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3) - Angular CLI version,Angular version,Node.js version,TypeScript version,   RxJS version are included here.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you so much for the explanation